# WSO2 GREG 5.0.0 M4 History Tables - Empty?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I noticed while doing a technical investigation that both the REG_CONTENT_HISTORY and REG_RESOURCE_HISTORY were both empty. I should have data in there, right? I updated content in and deleted default asset types, and still, no data in the tables.

Is this a configuration issue?

Comment: This is not a bug. resource history might saved in some other table.

Comment: Could you recommend a location it might have been saved in?

Comment: Did you analyse REG_LOG table?

Answer (score 0):

Usually these tables get populated when property versionResourcesOnChange is set to true in the registry.xml (SERVER_HOME/repository/conf). Otherwise history tables does not get populated.

`<versionResourcesOnChange>true</versionResourcesOnChange>`